# GIT Merge Code changed in commit and not include changes to this file in previous commits

Tags: git, svn, version-control, merge

I have two branches master and develop. In master branch following 3 commits were made for a same file -

Revision 1 - Line 1 Changed

Revision 2 - Line 2 Changed

Revision 3 - Line 3 Changed

I need to merge only Revision 2 - Line 2 into Develop.

Chery Picking Revision 2 results in conflict in which case I have to manually resolve conflict.

In SVN this was seamlessly achieved via merge. Since we have a large distributed teams, Merge into develop is done by module leads, manually resolving each conflict will be a huge task. How best can this be achieved in GIT.

Comment: It's hard to understand the exact question you're asking here. What have you tried before?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. Cherry picking revision 2 means you only get the change to line 2 but not the change to line 1.
If that's what you want, your approach is fine. Of course you'll need to resolve any conflicts that may arise, but if it's really just one line that should be trivial. (And svn is no different in that regard - when there are conflicts you need to resolve them manually).
If your question really is how to efficiently resolve conflicts, have a look at [git mergetool](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool)

However, this behaviour is not identical to a simple svn merge. Unless you explicitly perform a cherry picking merge, you would also get the change contained in revision 1.
If that's what you want you could use a simple `git merge` or `git rebase`.